# Access SQL Query: How to only display most recent record of duplicates

Tags: sql, database, sorting, ms-access

I'm very new to SQL and am trying to create a query that will sort a table (I've got that part working) and then only display the most recent record for each respective component and serial number.

Basically I'm making a check in/out system and want to only list the most recent status of for each particular component. Each time a component is checked in and out, it is issued a unique ID for that particular check in/out. Therefore I know that I can use the highest Unique ID for determining which record to display in my output table.

[image]

(Top graph is what I have, bottom is what I want)

How do I go about removing records in which the first two fields are duplicated?

Heres what I have so far:

```
SELECT [Check In/Out].Component, [Check In/Out].[Serial Number], [Check In/Out].[Unique ID], [Check In/Out].DateTime, [Check In/Out].Initials, [Check In/Out].[Check In/Out]
FROM [Check In/Out]
ORDER BY [Check In/Out].Component, [Check In/Out].[Serial Number], [Check In/Out].[Unique ID];
```

I found a similar code (shown below), however my attempt at modifying the code to work with mine failed:

```
SELECT Customers.ID, Customers.FullName, Customers.SaleDate
FROM Customers
WHERE [SaleDate] =
(SELECT Max([SaleDate])
FROM Customers AS X
WHERE X.[FullName] = [Customers].[FullName])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, Unique ID is the primary key so I wont have to worry about duplicates there. The "unit" that I don't want duplicates for only occurs when the Component and Serial Number fields are the same. One component can be checked in and out numerous times a day but I only want to see the most recent time it was checked in/out (therefore the record of interest will be the one with the highest Unique ID for that particular set of data with matching Component and Serial Numbers.) The Date and Initials are only there to help someone track down a component after running the query. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Access SQL, this could work:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM [Check In/Out] AS tA INNER JOIN (SELECT Component, [Serial Number],    
                                                MAX(Unique ID) AS highest_id
                                         FROM [Check In/Out]
                                         GROUP BY Component, [Serial Number]) AS  

   tB ON tA.Component = tB.Component                                                                                       
   AND                                                                                  
   tA.[Serial Number] = tB.[Serial Number]                                                                                  
   AND                                                                                  
   tA.[Unique ID] = tB.highest_id
```

Comment: I think @kbball and I posted nearly simultaneously...same solution, I just aliased both tables to save some writing. Let us know if it works!

Comment: It works! thanks so much! The only thing I had to fix was change MAX(Unique ID) to MAX([Check In/Out].[Unique ID]). You're a lifesaver!

Comment: Minor point: we don't call it Jet anymore. Since Access 2007 we had an ACE version of the engine. I suggest using 'Access SQL' as a generic term (which I think is reflected in the infor for the `ms-access` tag).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new query and call it "MaxId":

```
SELECT [Check In/Out].Component, [Check In/Out].[Serial Number],
    max ([Check In/Out].[Unique ID]) as max_id
FROM [Check In/Out]
group by [Check In/Out].Component, [Check In/Out].[Serial Number]
```

You can then join to this query from a new query:

```
SELECT
    [Check In/Out].Component, [Check In/Out].[Serial Number], 
    [Check In/Out].[Unique ID], [Check In/Out].DateTime, 
    [Check In/Out].Intials, [Check In/Out].[Check In/Out]
FROM
    [Check In/Out]
    INNER JOIN MaxId ON 
      [Check In/Out].[Serial Number] = MaxId.[Serial Number] AND
      [Check In/Out].Component = MaxId.Component
WHERE
  [Check In/Out].[Unique ID] = [MaxId].[max_id];
```